# how can I put my canvas next to my table automatically if the screen is wide enough and else underneath each other?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a table with data and a graph (chart.js) visualizing this data.
The graph is in a "canvas"-type.
I can't get them to be next to each other.

I tried:

1. float:left
2. putting them both in the same div
3. column-count

... all giving wrong results.
Float:left puts only a bit of the graph next to the table, in the same div gives no change at all and column-count behaves somewhat like float-left.

```
<script src="/Chart.js"></script>
<article>
<h2>my data</h2>
<table><caption>nice data</caption><thead>
<tr><th>some value</th><th>%</th><th>more values</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>€ 100,00</td><td>17,59%</td><td>10 0 09 39 09 </td></tr>
<tr><td>€ 250,00</td><td>5,86%</td><td>0 79 7 35 5 </td></tr>
<tr><td>€ 10 000,00</td><td>5,48%</td><td>09 09 36 56 05 </td></tr>
<tr><td>€ 100 000,00</td><td>5,01%</td><td>79 35 85 94 03 </td></tr>
<tr><td>€ 107,50</td><td>4,11%</td><td>89 69 49 09 53 </td></tr>
<tr><td>€ 1 000,00</td><td>3,06%</td><td>28 06 15 51 20 </td></tr>
<tr><td>€ 2 500,00</td><td>2,79%</td><td>10 39 77 17 25 </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<div style="height:80vh;"><canvas id="bedrag_perc"></canvas></div>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("bedrag_perc");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: [100, 107, 250, 1000, 10000, 100000, 3.14],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'so much data',
            data: ['17.59', '4.11', '5.86', '3.06', '5.48', '5.01', '41.11'],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        animation: { duration: 0 },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
});
</script> 
</article>
```

I would like to have the graph next to the table if the screen is wide enough, else underneath each other (responsive web design).

The actual result is that only half of the chart is next to the table.

Comment: you can use `display:flex;` and `flex-wrap:wrap;` it will do it for you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Because if I follow the steps in [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) I get indeed the two items on one row; but they are not responsive; on a mobile device they are still in one row.
If I then add flex-direction:column; then I get the old result back.

Comment: if you use `flex-wrap:wrap;` it will wrap the items one below another if they cant fit in the one row. like this https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_wrap

Answer (score 0):

i have used bootstrap to make it work. below is the link. hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/3vxtw786/1/`999`

Comment: Thanks! But I forgot that I was hoping for a solution without external requirements like bootstrap.

Comment: put both elements inside 1 div and add this css .outer{
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}

Comment: check this link